# Disable logs in MultiLoad and FastExport - Teradata

Tags: teradata, fastexport, mload

I'm working with a script in python that will first create mload or fastexport files depending on parameters and then within the script I start those files to insert/export data.

```
    result = subprocess.run(["{0} < {1}".format(file_type, file_path)], 
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                shell=True)
```

```
example: fexp < .../conf.fx
```

This however creates logs in /logs folder depending on the application: either MloadUpload.log or FExpDownload.log
Is there a parameter with which I could disable creation of log files by multiload and fastexport?
Can I do it from command line or within the config file? 
I can't find an option for this anywhere :/

Comment: Why in the world would you not want log files from your jobs? What if you have an error?

Comment: One of the requirements I need to meet is logs being optional

Comment: Are you sure those files are being created by multiload or fastexport utility? Those names don't look at all familiar.

Comment: Not so sure anymore, the log file starts with ```2019-12-11 16:29:50,654 - teradata.udaexec - INFO - Initializing UdaExec... ``` is this Teradata Python Module that is making the logs?

Comment: That is the older *teradata* module, yes. You can set configureLogging=false in the config file. But you don't need that module to run command-line utilities like fexp. And there is a newer, completely different *teradatasql* module that is preferred for applications where you do want a Python DBAPI driver.